# Block External Teams Domains and Exempt Users

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

the options to block external domains are org wide, but I have a need to exempt certain executives to allow external communications despite the org wide filter.

I haven't found any options or documentation that suggest this is possible, but wanted to check with this community to make sure I wasn't missing anything.

Thanks in advance!